# Check playwright doesnt redirect to another page when a redirect button is clicked

Tags: testing, playwright, playwright-test, automation-testing

I got a form which takes user data. I am building a simple test to check that the continue button will not redirect to another page if the data inputs are invalid or empty.

any ideas?

Many thanks,

:-)

I have tried using waitForNavigatiopn(), but it is now deprecated.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. We need more info to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better check for error messages on UI, and API calls if you need to check form data.

```js
// Error on UI
await expect(page.locator("error")).toBeVisible();

// Form still opened - page not redirected
await expect(page.locator("#username")).toBeVisible();

// Url not changed
const url = page.url();
await page.click("text=Continue");
await expect(page).toHaveURL(url)

// Wait for the error on redirect
expect(await page.waitForURL(/success/)).toThrowError();

// Wait for responses
await page.waitForResponse(/error/);
await page.waitForResponse(r => r.body.toString().includes("error"));
...
```